# ReactJS Appending Component to Specific ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, jsx

I'm having trouble "appending" a child component (`NewPageSidear`) to a specific ID higher up and outside (`Main`) the parent component (`NewPage`) that is loading the child component.

I have the following DOM structure that is created in `Main.jsx`, which is loaded on page load to `index.html`:

```
render(){
    return(
        <div id="wrapper" className="wrapper">
            <Header />
            <div id="content" className="content">
                <Sidebar />
                <div id="main" className="main">
                    <div className="section-title">
                        <h2>{this.state.pageTitle}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="main-content" className="main-content"></div>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**On page load, I do:**

```
ReactDOM.render(<Dashboard/>,document.querySelector('#main-content'));
```

ON the `Dashboard` page, I'll click a button that will execute the following and replace the `Dashboard` with `NewPage`:

```
ReactDOM.render(<NewPage/>,document.querySelector('#main-content'));
```

**My Problem is here:**

When `NewPage` loads, there is a child component, `NewPageSidebar` that I want to append to `#content`. If I can get `NewPageSidebar` to append `#content`, then I can use `componentWillUnmount` to remove `NewPageSidebar` when unmounted. But how do I get `NewPageSidebar` appended to `#content`? Any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
 ReactDOM.render(<NewPage newSidebar={true}/>,document.querySelector('#main-content'));
```

**And in the NewPage:**

```
render(){
    return(
        <div id="wrapper" className="wrapper">
            <Header />
            <div id="content" className="content">
                <Sidebar />
                {this.props.newSidebar ? <NewSidebar /> : null}
                <div id="main" className="main">
                    <div className="section-title">
                        <h2>{this.state.pageTitle}</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div id="main-content" className="main-content"></div>
                    <Footer />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Where will I put `ReactDOM.render(<NewPage newSidebar={true}/>,document.querySelector('#main-content'));` at?

Comment: Well, I thought you've already figured that out ?
Else I think you have framed the question wrong. What are your pending requirements in this case ?

Comment: I'm fine now. I've made so many changes today, that my mind is a little garbled. I just need to add newSidebar={true}. I just finished adding the other part of what you wrote.

Comment: Cool. Best of luck

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: Using `<NewPage newSidebar={true} />` but that doesn't seem to do anything. I'm already setting the mount state inside the child component, "NewPage", inside the `constructor` via this.state.mounted, and changing that value based on `componentDidMount()` and `componentWillUnmount()`. None of this seems to work to show the sidebar.

Comment: After playing around in a fiddle with some simple classes, it see,s as though the constructor(props){} is what's messing this up for me. <NewPage newSidebar={true}/> is not working because of it.